# Amazon Elastic Bean Stalk: error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am building a flask app on Elastic Bean Stalk. And after deploying I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error. When I checked the logs, I found that there was an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 32, in <module>
application.run(debug=True, port=server_port, host='0.0.0.0')
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 739, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 617, in run_simple
test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
mod_wsgi (pid=6577): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=6577): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
```

The application.py file is as follows

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

application.debug = True

# Application routes defined here
@application.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"


# Run the application
application.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I tried a lot. I don't get what is happening. After reading other stackoverflow questions, I've found that this is caused by not having root permissions. How will I run my WSGI script with root permission in elastic bean stalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
# Run the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The `application.run()` call should not be done when running under mod_wsgi. It is only appropriate when running that script from the command line. That 'if' statement will ensure that it isn't called under mod_wsgi.